# Return object from async method in JavaScript/Typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, async-await

I'm looking to return only object from my Typescript method because already I'm resolving promise and using them.I have tried many article to read and understand but how I'm thinking to solve this still didn't got.

```
protected async loadProjectsDemo () {
    const result = await this.someService.loadData().then(item => {
       return item;
    });
    return result;
}
```

I know I'm doing something wrong here because I'm new to JavaScript, so need some help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `.then` doesn't do anything here. Correct is simply `return await this.someService.loadData();`. What's the issue when doing so…?

Comment: I need object from loadProjectsDemo(), but it always return a promise, even in way you have suggested.

Comment: Yes, `loadProjectDemo` is an `async` function, which means it will always return a promise, which means it must be `await`ed as well (or treated as promise). There's no way for it to not return a promise.

Comment: Ok, so what solution here, because I'm not understanding, I have tried many other option, still not somewhere near to to it.

Comment: Whatever is calling `loadProjectDemo` must `await` it too. It's that simple.